# Selenium w/ Firefox not accepting HTTP Proxy IP with user authentication

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, geckodriver

I'm looking to use Selenium with a username/password authenticated proxy in Ruby. I realize that [most people use ProxyChain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68067000/using-a-proxy-with-selenium-and-ruby) when doing this in Chrome, but I'd like to use a solution without any additional gems since it doesn't play well on Heroku, plus I'm using Firefox so there seems to be a possible other option judging by [THIS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084652/firefox-geckodriver-not-accepting-http-proxy-ip-with-user-authentication) though it's written in Python.

I used the selenium docs to translate that code to Ruby, but Selenium is still not using my proxy when navigating to a webpage. Oddly enough when I refresh the page manually it prompts me for the username/password but it doesn't do that on the initial page load.

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

profile["network.proxy.type"] = 1
# proxy ip and port are fake for this example
profile["network.proxy.http"] = "182.192.157.60"
profile["network.proxy.http_port"] = 12345

# set the username and password
profile["network.proxy.socks_username"] = "my_username"
profile["network.proxy.socks_password"] = "my_password"

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(profile: profile)

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, options: options
```

If anyone has any ideas I would certainly appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to introduce you WATIR. This is a wrapper around ruby selenium binding. If you just move to watir code and raise a question by tagging WATIR, you may get reply soon.

Comment: @Rajagopalan WAITR's github repo says "this is a Selenium issue" https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/798. Do you know that there's a way to accomplish using an authenticated proxy with WAITR?

Comment: I never used Proxy.